# SQL Query - Not in a set of already in-use items

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select jobs that are not currently assigned to a user.

```
Users table: id | name
Jobs:        id | name
Assigned:    id | user_id | job_id | date_assigned
```

I want to select all the jobs that are not currently taken. Example:

Users:

```
id   |   name
--------------
1    |   Chris
2    |   Steve
```

Jobs

```
id   |  name
---------------
1    |  Sweep
2    |  Skids
3    |  Mop
```

Assigned

```
id   |   user_id  |   job_id    |   date_assigned 
-------------------------------------------------
1    |   1        |   1         |   2012-01-01
2    |   1        |   2         |   2012-01-02
3    |   2        |   3         |   2012-01-05
```

No two people can be assigned the same job. So the query would return

```
[1, Sweep]
```

Since no one is working on it since Chris got moved to Skids a day later.

So far:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    jobs
WHERE
    id
NOT IN
    (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT(job_id)
        FROM
            assigned
        ORDER BY
            date_assigned
        DESC
    )
```

However, this query returns NULL on the same data set. Not addressing that the sweep job is now open because it is not currently being worked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM jobs a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT a.job_id
    FROM assigned a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid
        FROM assigned
        GROUP BY user_id
    ) b ON a.id = b.maxid
) b ON a.id = b.job_id
WHERE b.job_id IS NULL
```

This gets the most recent job per user. Once we have a list of those jobs, we select all jobs that aren't on that list.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. But I will keep trying.

Comment: @user1549575 can you at least explain why it does not work? Is it an error, wrong result? Also, can you answer my question I asked in the question comments. What do you mean by "currently taken"?

Comment: It won't work because it doesn't answer the question.  The problem is not to select jobs that have never been assigned.  It is to correctly sort the assignment history.

Comment: It does not filter our the jobs that are currently taken, it displays all the jobs.

Comment: @Zane Bien With a little tweaking I got it working! Thank you. (I had to simplify my example a lot because my problem is much bigger)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this variant:

```
select * from jobs
 where id not in (
  select job_id from (
    select user_id, job_id, max(date_assigned)
      from assigned
  group by user_id, job_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want:

```
SELECT *
FROM jobs
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT job_id
                 from assigned
                 where user_id is not null
                )
```

This assumes that re-assigning someone changes the user id on the original assignment.  Does this happen?  By the way, I also simplified the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to be looking at a list of only current job assignments. Ordering isn't enough.  The way you have it set up, you need a distinct subset of job assignments from Assigned that are the most recent assignments.

So you want a grouping subquery something like

```
select job_id, user_id, max(date_assigned) last_assigned from assigned group by job_id, user_id
```

Put it all together and you get

```
select id, name from jobs
where id not in (
  select job_id as id from (
    select job_id, user_id, max(date_assigned) last_assigned from assigned 
    group by job_id, user_id
  )
)
```

As an extra feature, you could pass up the value of "last_assigned" and it would tell you how long a job has been idle for.